# Why non-breaking space is not allowed in css declarations?

Tags: css

I was fixing some non-working css style and found that non-breaking space (\u00A0) is not allowed in the css declarations and having it breaks parsing. 
It breaks reliably in all browsers, so it seems that such behavior is expected. Does anybody know why it is so?
[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tma6ya51/) Text should be red but it is not, removing non breaking space fixes it.

```js
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = ".text\u00A0{ color: red}";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

```html
<span class="text">red?</span>
```

Comment: why do you ever want a non breakable space like that

Comment: This is why many programmers recommend formatting code in lines of 80 characters or less. So that workarounds like this are not needed.

Comment: I don't need that space. But it appeared somehow in the css (probably by copy pasting it from somewhere), and broke css parsing silently. Also, javascript, for example, threats such spaces correctly, so it seemed to that is was sort of strange behavior

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. The no-break space *is* allowed in CSS, it just isn’t whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CSS, U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE is not whitespace. Only ASCII spaces, tabs, line breaks and form feeds count as whitespace. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html):

> Only the characters "space" (U+0020), "tab" (U+0009), "line feed" (U+000A), "carriage return" (U+000D), and "form feed" (U+000C) can occur in white space. Other space-like characters, such as "em-space" (U+2003) and "ideographic space" (U+3000), are never part of white space.

U+00A0 is not mentioned here, but since it is not one of the allowed characters, it's implied to be disallowed.

Since it's not being treated as whitespace, it has to be treated as part of the selector. From [section 4.1.3 of the same document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) (which *does* mention the code-point U+00A0, although by sheer coincidence):

> In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_)

The selector essentially becomes one that looks for an element with `class="text&nbsp;"`, where the non-breaking space is part of the class name:

```js
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = ".text\u00A0{ color: red}";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

```html
<span class="text">red?</span>
<span class="text&nbsp;">red!</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up. However, it still seems strange decision to allow that. It can only produce hard to trace bugs :(.

Answer (score 0):

That's because a non breaking space is a character like any other character. It *happens* to look like a space, but it's no different from "a" or "4" or "♥".

```js
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = ".text\u00A0{ color: red}";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

```html
<span class="text ">red?</span>
```

As you can see, by adding a non-breaking space to the class name, your example works.